# Can relaxed memory model reorder on same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I was wondering, does `memory_order_relaxed` allow unconstrained reordering of code on the same thread? For example:

```
// All on the same thread
std::atomic_int num(10);

std::cout << num.load(memory_order_relaxed) << "\n";
num.store(0, memory_order_relaxed);
```

Is it possible that 0 is printed? (In the actual code another thread is modifying `num`, but its unrelated)

Comment: If no other thread is modifying it, the ordering wouldn't make any difference. It's only then two threads operate on the same thing at the same time that the ordering matters.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh, ok. So in this example its **not** possible that 0 is printed, right?

Comment: No. And the order in which the operations takes place doesn't matter because no other thread is observing them. Maybe the write of 0 is emitted to memory before the load is executed, but how could you tell? Nobody is looking at that.

Comment: `Maybe the write of 0 is emitted to memory before the load is executed, but how could you tell` Wait, so it **is** possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you could never tell. Nothing is observing that behavior.

Comment: But I have the `std::cout` printing it out

Comment: How could you tell whether the ten that was printed out was actually what was read from memory? It could read a zero from memory but still output a ten because that's how the CPU is designed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry, I'm kinda confused. When it prints the 10 out, doesn't it have to read it first?

Comment: It could, for example, do the read but ignore the value and just output a 10 because it knows that's what it wrote and no other thread invalidated that write. So long as the CPU outputs a 10, it can reorder as much as it wants.

Comment: Oohhhhh ok. I understand better now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the formal ordering rules, this guarantee follows from the fact that "sequenced before" implies "happens before", and the promise of read-write coherence.

Answer (score 8):

"Reordering" is not a useful way to think about multithreaded code, because it is so imprecise. Instead, we should observe the following:

- Each thread executes in order.
- Each atomic variable in the program has a single modification order, on which *all threads agree*.
- There is no single order in which *different* atomic variables are modified (unless such atomic variables are accessed solely through sequentially consistent operations).
- A thread might not observe side effects on two *different* atomic variables modified by another thread in the same order in which such modifications actually occurred. For example, thread 1 can modify atomic variable `a` and then atomic variable `b`. Thread 2 may observe the new value of `b` and then the old value of `a`. This is what most people think of as "reordering".

In your question, the answer is no, 0 cannot be printed. This is due to the first rule above: each thread executes in order.

Comment: How can one explain [this example on relaxed ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering)? In particular the fact that D can be completed before C.